# Elasticsearch change primary shards number

Tags: elasticsearch, devops

i have 3 node elasticsearch cluster and i have index with
1 primary and 1 replica shards
so i want to change the primary shard number from 1 to 2 using this method https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/indices-split-index.html but in the doc said that

```
The number of primary shards in the target index must be a multiple of the number of primary shards in the source index
```

but in my case 1 * 1 = 1
so how can i do resize from 1 primary shards to 2 primary shards correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The incremental resharding is not allowed in elasticsearch. So, if you want to increase the number of primary shards from 1 to 2 is impossible. However, you have two options to reach this goal:

- Split your index to 4 using this API and then Shrink it to index with 2 primary shards using this api [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-shrink-index.html)
- Create a new index with two primary shards and reindex your data to this index using this API [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html).

I suggest you the second option.

Comment: But in the discuss said that 2 is a multiple of 1 so that is fine. Since you are splitting shards they all need to split the same way. You can split a single shard into 2, 3 or 4 etc shards, but can e.g. not go from 2 to 3 or from 2 to 5.

Comment: Can I see the link of discuss? Maybe they are talking about a different version of elasticsearch that you have installed.

Comment: sure https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-change-primary-shards-number/251716

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the response shows other things. I Suggest you to use `reindex`. You create a index with two shards and `reindex` your data into that index. after that you can delete your first index. you can also set alias for new index to work with name of the first index, as well.

Comment: Thank you my Iranian friend! i will be very glad to visit Iran in the future

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to see you if it would be possible.